# What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For example:

```
div > p.some_class {
  /* Some declarations */
}
```

What exactly does the `>` sign mean?

Answer (score 800, accepted):

`>` is the [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators), sometimes mistakenly called the direct descendant combinator.<sup>1</sup>

That means the selector `div > p.some_class` only matches paragraphs of `.some_class` that are nested **directly inside** a `div`, and not any paragraphs that are nested further within. This implies that every element matching `div > p.some_class` necessarily also matches `div p.some_class`, with the [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) (space), so the two are understandably often confused.

An illustration comparing the child combinator with the descendant combinator:

```css
div > p.some_class { 
    background: yellow;
}

div p.some_class { 
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="some_class">Some text here</p>     <!-- [1] div > p.some_class, div p.some_class -->
    <blockquote>
        <p class="some_class">More text here</p> <!-- [2] div p.some_class -->
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

Which elements are matched by which selectors?

1. **Matched by both `div > p.some_class` and `div p.some_class`**
   This `p.some_class` is located directly inside the `div`, hence a parent-child relationship is established between both elements. Since "child" is a type of "descendant", any child element is by definition also a descendant. Therefore, both rules are applied.
2. **Matched by only `div p.some_class`**
   This `p.some_class` is contained by a `blockquote` within the `div`, rather than the `div` itself. Although this `p.some_class` is a descendant of the `div`, it's not a child; it's a grandchild. Therefore, only the rule with the descendant combinator in its selector is applied.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Many people go further to call it "direct child" or "immediate child", but that's completely unnecessary (and incredibly annoying to me), because a child element **is immediate *by definition*** anyway, so they mean the exact same thing. There's no such thing as an "indirect child".</sub>

Comment: +1 Is it really called a *child selector*? If so, that is pretty misleading. I would of thought `#something a` would be a child selector.

Comment: @alex: [yes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) :) `#something a` could mean `a` is a grandchild or great^n grandchild of `#something` (it doesn't take into account depth of nesting).

Comment: Well I mean it is still a child... a grandchild maybe :P

Comment: @alex it's called the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), the space is called the [descendent combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

Comment: When someone is their grandparent's child, we're dealing with a really nasty instance of incest. Happily, that is impossible in HTML.

Comment: Flagging this thread on suspicion of promoting textual pedophilia and incest (kidding)

Comment: Annoying or not to call it a direct child it makes it instantly clear to the uneducated, I think it's a good description.

Comment: I don't hear any laymen calling their kids their direct children for the sake of clarity.

Comment: The term "direct" is pretty confusing. In [other areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineal_descendant) it means "not via a sibbling or similar". That isn't something HTML does (unless you consider elements which are moved by JS, a consideration CSS doesn't care about).

Comment: @Quentin: That's true. Perhaps "immediate" is more appropriate here. I can't think of any good alternative to just "child", but people seem insistent on conflating "child" and "descendant"...

Comment: @BoltClock — Maybe "the child combinator, sometimes mistakenly called the direct descendant combinator"?

Comment: Am I missing something? Child would be next level down. descendant could be any number of levels down. So in that case, child == direct descendant. So why is it "sometimes mistakenly called direct descendant combinator"? direct child would be wrong, but direct descendant seems correct? Please do correct me if im wrong here.

Comment: The footnote seems correct as it talks about direct child, which I agree is pointless as a child is the immediate next level down anyway, but the main text seems wrong for the reasons above.

Comment: I would say: `"> is the child combinator/direct descendant, sometimes mistakenly called the direct child combinator"`

Comment: @redfox05: See Quentin's comments just above yours.

Answer (score 61):

`>` (greater-than sign) is a CSS Combinator.

> A combinator is something that explains the relationship between the selectors.

A CSS selector can contain more than one simple selector. Between the simple selectors, we can include a combinator.

There are four different combinators in CSS3:

1. descendant selector (space)
2. child selector (>)
3. adjacent sibling selector (+)
4. general sibling selector (~)

**Note:** `<` is not valid in CSS selectors.

[image]

**For example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div > p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <p>Paragraph 1 in the div.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2 in the div.</p>
  <span><p>Paragraph 3 in the div.</p></span> <!-- not Child but Descendant -->
</div>

<p>Paragraph 4. Not in a div.</p>
<p>Paragraph 5. Not in a div.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

[More information about CSS Combinators](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors

Comment: @premraj Thank you for the excellent explanation of parent-child css selectors!

Comment: What does it mean then when you get something like `.entry-content > * {"code" }` which is followed by `.entry-content {"other code" }`? Doesn't `.entry-content > *` cover all the children of `entry-content`?

Answer (score 14):

As others mention, it's a child selector. Here's the appropriate link.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Comment: Thank you very much for the link ! I discovered also the "Adjacent sibling selectors" there.

Comment: You'll find [browser support](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector#compatibilitysection) on Sitepoint. Doesn't work in IE6 if it matters for your projects, OK everywhere else. This resource is esp. useful for siblings, :nth-child() etc where support is still incomplete

Answer (score 10):

It matches `p` elements with class `some_class` that are *directly* under a `div`.

Answer (score 6):

> ( child selector) was introduced in css2.
> `div p` select all p elements who are decedent of div element, whereas `div > p` select only child p elements, not grand child, great grand and so on.

```
<style>

  div p{ color:red }       /* match all p in div */
  div > p{ color:blue }    /* match only children p of div*/

</style>

<div>
   <p>para tag, child and decedent of p.</p>
   <ul>
       <li>
            <p>para inside list. </p>
       </li>
   </ul>
   <p>para tag, child and decedent of p.</p>
</div>
```

For more information on CSS Ce[lectors and their use, check my blog,
[css selectors](http://tutorial.techaltum.com/cssselectors.html) and [css3 selectors](http://tutorial.techaltum.com/css3-selectors.html)

Answer (score 5):

All `p` tags with class `some_class` which are direct children of a `div` tag.

Answer (score 3):

html

```
<div>
    <p class="some_class">lohrem text (it will be of red color )</p>    
    <div>
        <p class="some_class">lohrem text (it will  NOT be of red color)</p> 
    </div>
    <p class="some_class">lohrem text (it will be  of red color )</p>
</div>
```

css

```
div > p.some_class{
    color:red;
}
```

All the direct children that are `<p>` with `.some_class` would get the style applied to them.

Answer (score 1):

The greater sign ( > ) selector in CSS means that the selector on the right is a direct descendant / child of whatever is on the left.

An example:

```
article > p { }
```

Means only style a paragraph that comes after an article.