# Are "div > p" & "div p" same?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hey, I've an obvious question.

For code like:

```
<div>
     <p>We want to format this text :)</p>
</div>
```

Some people use selector like:

```
div > p {
     something
}
```

And others:

```
div p {
     something
}
```

What's the difference in this case? In my opinion - none?

And by the way, isn't the descendant item always a child?! What's the difference between the two? I'm reading w3.org but can't get it :)

Thank you!

Comment: That is not a CSS3 selector. That's a CSS2 selector.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Simple:

```
 div > p
```

affects only *direct children.*

```
 div p
```

affects grandchildren, grandgrandchildren etc. *as well.* (Won't make a difference in your example)

The child selector [isn't supported by IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Comment: ... and we can't wait for IE6 to die, so that we can finally use those damn child selectors :)

Comment: It doesn't make a sense to me. If that's true, then "div > p" equals "div + p" O.o

Comment: @fomicz no. The `+` selector selects the *next sibling*

Comment: a + b is a direct sibling relationship. a > b is a parent-child relationship.

Comment: @BalusC you clearly have no idea what you are talking about. CSS4 will support Manga selectors: e.g. `<3`  for HTML elements that are *cute*, and `^_^` for *funny* content.

Comment: @Pekka: So what would `i <3 #stackoverflow` mean?

Comment: @BoltClock It will match an image of a unicorn with the ID `stackoverflow` in an italic paragraph.

Comment: @Pekka: Awesome. Sadly the unicornification has worn off me :(

Answer (score 20):

Pekka has explained it in theory in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948846/are-div-p-div-p-same/3948857#3948857). Based on his answer, and [my answer to another question about the `>` combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-means-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905), I'll provide an illustration, modified to address this question.

Consider the following block of HTML, and your example CSS selectors. **I use a more elaborate example so I can show you the difference between both of your selectors:**

```
<div>
    <p>The first paragraph.</p>                 <!-- [1] -->
    <blockquote>
        <p>A quotation.</p>                     <!-- [2] -->
    </blockquote>
    <div>
        <p>A paragraph after the quotation.</p> <!-- [3] -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Which `<p>`s are selected by which selectors?**

First off, *all of them match `div p`* because they are `<p>` elements situated *anywhere within* a `<div>` element.

That makes `div > p` more specific, which begs the next question:

**Which `<p>`s are selected by `div > p`?**

1. **Selected**

   This paragraph `<p>` is a child, or a direct descendant, of the outermost `<div>`. That means it's not immediately contained by any other element than a `<div>`. The hierarchy is as simple as the selector describes, and as such it's selected by `div > p`.
2. **Not selected**

   This `<p>` is found in a `<blockquote>` element, and the `<blockquote>` element is found in the outermost `<div>`. The hierarchy would thus look like this:

   ```
   div > blockquote > p
   ```

   As the paragraph is directly contained by a blockquote, it's *not* selected by `div > p`. However, it *can* match `blockquote > p` (in other words, it's a child of the `<blockquote>`).
3. **Selected**

   This paragraph lives in the inner `<div>`, which is contained by the outer `<div>`. The hierarchy would look like this:

   ```
   div > div > p
   ```

   It doesn't matter if there are more `<div>`s nested within each other, or even if the `<div>`s are contained by other elements. As long as this paragraph is directly contained by its own `<div>`, it will be selected by `div > p`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Well, OP did ask for the difference :P

Comment: +1 this answer qualifies for the `:o` selector (astonishingly detailed explanation)

Comment: @Pekka: Haha! [This isn't my only one](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:106224+%5Bcss-selectors%5D) :)

Comment: Still a great answer in 2015. +1 =)