# What’s the difference between the CSS selectors “div p” and “div > p”?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “div > p” & “div p” same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948846/are-div-p-div-p-same)

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) the page i'm using as a reference for CSS, please note that i only started learning HTML/CSS this morning.

I'm confused about two of the selectors, quoting the site, the "div p" selector `selects all <p> elements inside <div> elements`, and the "div > p" selector `selects all <p> elements where the parent is a <div> element`.

What is the difference between those two? Examples where these two selectors can't be used interchangably would be helpful, if possible.

Comment: http://w3fools.com/ But in any case, the `>` means directly a descendant of.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`div > p` selects only the `<p>` elements that are immediate children of a `<div>`.

So:

```
div > p
```

will select this paragraph:

```
<div>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

but will not select this paragraph:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>This will not get selected</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, your second example will still get selected, because it is still a `<p>` directly within a `<div>`

Comment: Welp, that should do the trick... :)

Comment: also you ended your <table> with a </div>, i'm gonna take this answer, because it's the simplest nad still satisfies the question fully

Comment: Looks like a revision history problem with so many people editing at the same time. #bug

Answer (score 8):

Selecting all `p` tags inside of a `div` means ALL `p` tags inside of a `div`... where as the second means the `p` tags that are just one level below a `div`.

From [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/) #8:

> The difference between the standard X Y and X > Y is that the latter will only select direct children. For example, consider the following markup.

Consider this example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">
  <p>asdf</p>
  <div>
    <p>asdf</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <p>asdf</p>
  <div>
    <p>asdf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.one p {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color:#F00;
}

div.two > p {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color:#0F0;
}
```

In the first one, both `p` tags will be colored red (`#F00`) because it selects all `p` tags within the `div`. In the second, only the first `p` tag will be blue (`#0F0`) because it only selects direct descendants.

[**DEMO**](http://cssdesk.com/8GsBX)

Comment: that site you used for the demo's really usefull

Answer (score 1):

`div p` is the descendant selector, it will match any `p` elements which have a `div` higher in their hierarchy. `div > p`, which uses the child selector, will only match `p` elements whose direct parent is a `div`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**: `"div p"` implies All the `<p>`'s will be selected

```
<div>
  <p id=1> 
    <p id=2>
      <p id=3></p>
    </p>
  </p>
</div>
```

**Case 2**: `"div > p"` only `<p id=1>` will be selected i.e. all `p` tags with `div` as the immediate parent

Comment: This is a weird example - you should probably make your example HTML at least mostly valid.

Answer (score 0):

`div p` will match any `p` with an ancestor `div`, which need not be its parent. So all these match:

```
<div><p>Matches</p></div>
<div><form><p>Matches</p></form></div>
<div><section><blockquote><p>Matches</p></blockquote></section></div>
```

`div > p` will only match a `p` with a direct parent `div`. Like this:

```
<div><p>Matches</p></div>
```

(You will note that everything matched by `div > p` is also matched by `div p`.)