# Remove ::before or ::after pseudo element CSS definition

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

### Some background

I'm displaying forms in my application and I enclose each field (or a related set of them) in an `UL/LI` element. This is an example:

```
<ul class="form">
    <li class="required">
        <label for="...">Field label</label>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" ... />
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

As you can see I set a class `required` on required field's `LI` element, so when their `label` is displayed I define an `::after` pseudo element, that adds a red asterisk after it:

```
ul.form li.required label::after
{
    content: " *";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f66;
}
```

### The problem

The problem I'm having is when I have a list of checkboxes or radio buttons in my `<div class="field">` container. To have labels beside radio buttons or checkboxes clickable, they must be contained in a `label`.

```
<ul class="form">
    <li class="required">
        <label for="...">Radio button set</label>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="radio" name="RBSet" value="1" id="RBSet1" /><label for="RBSet1">First</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="RBSet" value="2" id="RBSet2" /><label for="RBSet2">Second</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="RBSet" value="3" id="RBSet3" /><label for="RBSet3">Third</label><br/>
            ...
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The problem is of course that each label beside my radio button displays an asterisk because it's also contained inside the `li.required` element.

### Question

How do I remove `::after` pseudo element from all `label` elements that are contained in a `div.field`? Do I have to actually define it but set its content to an empty string or is it possible to remove it all together?

I could change my style definition for `::after` to

```
ul.form li.required > label::after
{
    content: " *";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f66;
}
```

but I want to avoid these special CSS selectors for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just apply the pseudo-element to `label`s that are children of `.required` using the [child combinator `>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-means-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905):

```
ul.form li.required > label::after
{
    content: " *";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f66;
}
```

The `>` combinator has better IE compatibility (IE7 and up) than the `::after` pseudo-element (IE9 and up). If you're able to use `::after`, there is no reason not to use `>`. In fact, IE support for pseudo-elements is so inconsistent that IE8 recognizes CSS2 `:after` but not CSS3 `::after`. Your code would thus not work on IE8 unless you use `:after`, and to support IE7 and older you need a JavaScript fix.

Comment: I edited my question just before you've submitted your answer. For compatibility reasons I would like to avoid special selectors...

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: See my edit. `>` has better compatibility with IE than `::after`.

Comment: You're right. If I'm using pseudo elements I shouldn't have problems using advanced selectors either. :) And I'm using single double-collon notation anyway. I've just written it here in the more strict (by spec) way.

Comment: Note that screen readers do not reliably announce generated content so users that employ them will not be aware of the asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead with the child-of selector. If you look at [this compatibility table](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) you will see that all browsers that support `:after` also support the child-of selector `>`.

If you need maximum compatibility (with IE7), consider using a backround image rather than the `:after` tag. Example:

```
ul.form li.required label
{
  background: url(/images/star.png) top right no-repeat;
  padding-right: 10px;
}


ul.form li.required div.field label
{
  background: none;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also clear the `::after` content for all `field` labels:

```
ul.form li.required label::after
{
    content: " *";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f66;
}


ul.form li.required div.field label::after
{
    content: " ";
}
```

Comment: I don't think you cleared them actually, but rather re-defined them with different content.