# Is there a way to mix ids and classes with > in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

What I want to do is something like:

```
#div_id > .some_class 
{
}
```

I don't want to change the class everywhere.  I only want to change the class if it in that particular div.

Is ther some other way to do that same thing?

Comment: Maybe this only works for certain browsers, etc?

Comment: Does it also have to be a direct child or can it be a grand child?

Comment: Thanks all, I think I got it.  A few of you had it right, thanks.

Comment: @Grae: The only known browser to not understand it is IE 6 and below.

Comment: If you need an illustration on how `>` works you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-means-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already stumbled upon the answer yourself:

```
#div_id > .class {
    /* CSS magic */
}
```

This selects `.class` if it is the *direct* descendant of `#div_id`. For all descendants regardless of depth, use the selector `#div_id .class` instead.

See also [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urdh/sB3k9/).

Comment: You know, honestly, I don't know why people need to say "*direct* child". The word "direct" is pretty much implied.

Comment: @BoltClock: True. Replaced "child" with "descendant", which is what I really meant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your question already contains the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) CSS selector and will target the elements with class  `.some_class` that are *children* of the element with id `div_id`, so if you have only one `<div>` with an id of `div_id` then it will *only* target the child elements with the class `some_class`. So it should work as already expected, except in IE6 of course which does not support that selector natively.

If you want to select grandchildren, use the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

- Child combinator `body > p`
- Descendant combinator `body p`

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have the answer there. If you want to modify all classes with in a div then the selector would be `div#id .this_class`. If it's just one instance of the class inside the `div` (say you have a `div` called 'test' with three `div`s with a class of 'test_class' then you could either use the `:nth-child()` selector or the `:first-of-type` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. Note that the > operator will only affect the children of the DIV not any lower decendants (i.e. grandchildren). Remove the > to affect everything inside the DIV with the class .some_class.