# nth-of-type not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got some simple markup

```
<div class='1'>
    <div class='11'></div>
    <div class='12'>
        <div class='121'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm using the following CSS to try and target the .11 and .12

```
div div:nth-of-type(1) { // some rules for the first div }
div div:nth-of-type(2) { // some rules for the second div }
```

However, it seems that div .121 is being targeted by the first rule. Is there a reason for this?

How would i target .11 in the first rule and .12 in the second only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `div.121` is the first `div`-type child of `div.12`.

To exclude it, qualify your `div.1`'s class and add the child combinator `>`, which will only match children of `div.1` rather than any element inside it ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-means-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905) illustrates another example):

```
div.1 > div:nth-of-type(1)
div.1 > div:nth-of-type(2)
```

Comment: Worked a treat, care to explain what the `>` is for the people who stumble across this in a couple of months.

Comment: @dotty: I added a link that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Because div.121 is *also* the first div that is a child of a div, and is therefore matched by the same selector.