# When to use `>` sign in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “>” mean in CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

I came across many many websites and I saw many of them use this type of notation in their css file for creating navigation bar like :

```
#navigation ul li > ul {
  /* some code in between */
}
```

but when i omit the `>` sign as

```
#navigation ul li ul {
  /* some code in between */
}
```

this still works the same way.

what is the difference and when to use `>` sign ?

Comment: Useful link about selectors: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: ul > li is the same as ul li. List item in this ul list is a direct descendant of ul.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`>` Means the direct child of a selector, so

`li > a` will ONLY match an `<a>` which is directly inside an `<li>` for example.

If the html was `<li><span><a>` the `<a>` would not be matched.

Removing the `>` will match any `<a>` nested inside an `<li>`, irrespective of other things around it, so `li a` would match the `<a>` in

`<li><a>` but also in `<li><span><a>`, for example.

Here's more information on direct Child selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: That's a very bad example as it's invalid markup (`p` cannot be a child of `ul`). It's so bad, in fact, that the selector `ul > li` **will** match the `li` in your example in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't thinking with the example in terms of valid, it was just to prove a point and avoid using many nested li's / ul's for simplicities sake

Answer (score 7):

The `>` means a child element - it is the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). That is, *directly* / *immediately* nested after.

So, in your first example, the `ul` at the end of the selector must be directly descending from the `li`.

Answer (score 3):

The "li > ul" syntax specifies that the ul must be a child of li. "li ul" instead says that the the styled ul is descendant of li, no matter how many levels below.

Answer (score 2):

```
selector[1] > selector[2]{ 
[property]: value 
}
```

This is called the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). In browsers that support it, it applies the styles to selector2 child elements of selector1.

Edit:
The second one you use I believe is called the [Descendant selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

They should work identically, but it's there's a little difference. The decendant selector will apply to ALL decendants ,whereas the child selector applies only to the direct children of the parent.

Comment: They don't work "identically" then, do they?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `>` when you want to target a direct descendant.

For example, `.foo > .bar` would target `.bar` only if it is the direct child, while `.foo .bar` would target any descendant of `.foo` that has the class `.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

`>` is to be used when the second operand/element is a **child** of the first operand/element. When it's omitted; **descendants** are matched, which *includes* children.

---

Therefore, if your HTML is structured as you suggested (#navigation ul li ul) then if you have  the following in your CSS:

```
#navigation ul {color:red;}
```

Then both `#navigation ul` *AND* `#navigation ul li ul` will be coloured red (the text) as they *BOTH* are **descendants** of `#navigation ul`.

But if you had the following in your CSS:

```
#navigation > ul {color:red;}
```

Then *only* `#navigation ul` would be coloured red as it is the only `ul` which is a direct child of `#navigation`

Answer (score 0):

`>` is the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

It will only select immediate children of the previous element. If it there is a

```
#navigation ul li ul li ul
```

element it will **not** be affected by the

```
#navigation ul li > ul
```

selector. But the

```
#navigation ul li ul
```

**will** be.

---

EDIT: @[Nix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830134/nix) [is right](http://jsfiddle.net/YcsbS/), but he isn't telling the whole truth it seems. *Why isn't the `p`-enclosed `ul` ignored but only the `span`-enclosed? `display: block` vs `inline` perhaps? Who knows?

Comment: This is not exactly true in this instance, as in this example using `>` it will target any `<ul/>` that is a direct descendant of `<li/>` — even if it is buried in ten other `ul li`'s. It just means it will not target `li span ul`.

Comment: Regarding your edit, @Nix *is* telling the whole truth. The behavior you're seeing is caused by the fact that the opening `<ul>` tag happens to close the opening `<p>` tag just before it. This makes the second nested `ul` really a child of the `li` above it, as well as the adjacent sibling of that `p`. It has nothing to do with `display: block` vs `inline`.

Comment: This does not happen with the `<span>` tag because the closing tag is required, unlike `<p>`, so the DOM is constructed with the `ul` being actually inside the `span`.

Comment: @BoltClock, It has to do with the tag type. XHTML( strict)? would not close the ´<p>` tag without complaining, is that correct?

Comment: @jwandborg: Yes, so if you serve XHTML (and not just with the strict XHTML doctype), the `<ul>` will be contained within the `<p>` in XHTML-compliant browsers. The implicit closing tag rule is part of HTML, not XHTML. (This is where things get complicated and confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

The ">" selector is the child selector, space is the descendant selector. If tag3 is inside of tag2, which is inside tag1, and you use a child selector, then your css rule won't apply to tag3 if you refer to tag3 inside of tag1, however, if you use the descendant selector, tag3 will be transitively inside tag1. This means that he descendant selector is more general than the child selector.

```
#navigation ul li > ul {
  /* some code in between */
}
```

is more specific than

```
#navigation ul li ul {
  /* some code in between */
}
```

because between the li tag inside the ul tag inside the tag with the id of navigation needs ul to be a direct child in the first example and in the second example ul doesn't need to be directly the child of li, li might have a child which is the parent of ul.

Comment: You're using the word "specific" very loosely here. In terms of *selector specificity* both of these selectors are equal. If you put the `#navigation ul li ul` rule *after* the `#navigation ul li > ul` rule, it will override.