# What is the difference between these two methods of css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
#nav li a{
  ..
}
```

and

```
#nav>li>a{
  ..
}
```

Please help me. I think both are same don't work same.

Comment: `parent > child` vs `ancestor any_descendant`

Comment: Please explain in simple language..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it?noredirect=1&lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787134/when-to-use-sign-in-css?noredirect=1&lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487483/what-does-mean-in-css?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The thing I understand from your first comment is that with ">" we can access only the items with in the class not the items of other class. But without ">" sign we can access all the items of that class and also the items of the class within the previous class.
Am I right?

Comment: Example: `a c` matches c in `<a><b><c>..</c></b><a>`. `a > c` does *not* match because c is *not* a direct child of a. `a > c` will match `<a><c>..</c></a>`.

Comment: Okay thanks.. Now i understand you completely.

Answer (score 2):

## nav li a{

..
}

-- at any depth of parent-child relation
and

## nav>li>a{

..
}

-- at first level of parent-child relation