# CSS - linked div affects children

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

Is there a way that "a" does not affect texts inside the div? Just the div itself?
I dont want them to be underlined. And no, i cant change "a"'s text-decoration to none, because i need it for regular links.

```
<a href="#">
<div style="smthing">
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
<span>text</span>
</div>
</a>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the **direct child selector** `>`

```
a > div { styles: go here; }
```

It will only affect "the `div` element which is a direct child of `a` element"

Note that some properties have `inherit` as a value by default. Those properties will need to be overridden.

Comment: By the way, remember that an 'a' wrapping a 'div' is not valid unless you adopt an html5 doctype.

Comment: [It's simply called the "child selector".](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3225905/106224) Also note that some properties cannot be overridden in descendant elements either. `text-decoration`, as mentioned in the question, is one of those properties.