# CSS child selector but have an a tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can't get the syntax for :nth(3) selector on this a tag, in the 3rd li tag. 
What a mouthful. Is it even possible?

On this website

[www.cutlassandcane.com/shopping/](http://cutlassandcane.com/shopping/)

I am trying to change the color of the 3rd menu item. Bandoli to have red font. It is prestashop so I cannot add span tags around it, asit was cause issues elsewhere.

So, my question is, is there a way to do it through CSS using the 3 rd child, or nth, selector?

```
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    color:black;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:nth-child()`, like this:

```css
.sf-menu > li:nth-child(3) > a {
    color: #c0474c;    
}
```

Note that `:nth-child()` is [only supported in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3). It doesn't work in IE8 or lower.

Comment: thank you it worked. I used .sf-menu li:nth-child(3) a,  because I didn't know what the ">" is for. What is the great than for?

Comment: It's the [child combinator](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector). It's supported in all modern browsers. You do need to use it in this instance, or you'll end up selecting elements that you don't intend to.

Comment: [Totally plugging this to answer OP's comment.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to say `.sf-menu > li:nth-child(3) > a`?

Comment: You're right of course. Without the child combinators, it also selects a bunch of the submenu links. I didn't notice one of them had a submenu.

Comment: Sorry, I was addressing the OP, not your solution :) Otherwise I'd have commented on the answer - for some reason I didn't get a timely "new answer added" notification...

Comment: I see, so this would have been if I  had a submenu under Bandoli, but I don't so no harm no foul, BUT, good to know. THanks, it is working.