# Confusion about two different CSS syntax to select nested elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “>” mean in CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

CSS has the following two syntaxes which seem to be doing the same thing. Selecting a nested element.

```
div span

div > span
```

Am I missing something, or are these two indeed equivalent selectors ?

Comment: Could you mark it as duplicate instead of closing it? I asked the question here, because SO normally focuses on more programming related questions. Thanks the link helped. Edit: I guess you are right, this does belong to SO.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't mark things as duplicate if the duplicate is on a different StackExchange site from Webmasters. (It's a limitation/design choice of the SE software.) Sorry!

Comment: @Nick: Now that the question has been migrated, I've closed it here. Thanks for flagging!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. The first one is the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors), while the second is the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

Quick example:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this markup `.a > .c` will select nothing, while `.a .c` and `.a > .b > .c` will select the innermost element.

Answer (score 3):

```
div span
```

Will select any span that is inside any div. This could be multiple levels deep.

```
div > span
```

Will only select any spans that are the direct descendants of a div.
More info about child selectors -> http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html

Comment: Thanks for the link... it's very useful.