# Select this but not that

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a menu like:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="forum.php">Community</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="forum.php">Forum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>               
        <li><a>Account Management</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm using the following to style the 'Community' link:

```
nav ul li:nth-child(2) a
```

But that also styles the 'Forum' link which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add some child selectors, otherwise your selector will ignore nesting levels and always select any `a` elements that's nested within your second `li`:

```
nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a
```

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905) for an illustration of the child selector.