# How do you define this CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Code:

```
#navigation > ul > li > a
```

Descendant and child.

Is "a" child of li, or the holde code. 
Or is "a" child li but descendant to the rest. I'm not quite into the rules. Hope you can help me out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the selector one by one. Whether you read from left to right or right to left is up to you, but selectors are basically linear.

This selector means:

> Select any `a` element
>   that is a child of a `li` element (`li > a`)
>   that is a child of `ul` element (`ul > li`)
>   that is a child of an element with the ID `navigation` (`#navigation > ul`).

Every element that is a child of its parent is also a descendant of its parent *as well as that parent's parents*. To put it in simpler terms: an element that's contained within another element is that element's descendant. Note that it's also a child *only* when it's directly contained within that element (and not something else nested in between) — people often refer to this as a "direct child" for emphasis, but a child is *by definition* directly contained in its parent anyway.

Thus, the structure of this selector *implies* the following:

- `a` is a descendant of `#navigation`, `ul` and `li` but only a child of `li`
- `li` is a descendant of `#navigation` and `ul`, but only a child of `ul`
- `ul` is both a descendant and a child of `#navigation`

Additional reading:

- [Descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) and [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) from the spec
- [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905) (with an illustration)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. :)
But what is Descendant then?