# what is the use of > in css?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “>” mean in CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

what's the use of > in css? like this ***ul li:hover > ul*** or ***ul li > li***. >_<, i'm still new to web dev. can tell me when and how to use this >? and what does it call? like uh greater than? lol im sorry im really new.

```
#navMenu li > ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}

#navMenu li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
}

#navMenu li > ul li > ul
{
    left:100%;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: This and many other selectors are listed here in a neat DIY article:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Child & Descendant Selector!

In simple words, the `>` character selects the immediate child and applies the styles.

#### For more information, take a look at [Child and Sibling Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Comment: @BoltClock : Answer should be correct, whether it is copied or not (doesn't matter)

Comment: @Ran: It matters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism

Comment: @BoltClock I have also mentioned the source. Now I got a **-8** rep! Chris Coyer's CSS Tricks is the best place for CSS stuff.

Comment: Then what is the meaning of referring from somewhere? How do you do that to get the user know what he wants???

Comment: Your original answer didn't contain the link, and as a result it was flagged, but now that it contains the link it's good enough for attribution, so I've undeleted your answer. Please be very careful next time when making references.

Comment: @BoltClock I agreed I copied. But I edited and then pasted the link. Before that you deleted it. I will be extra careful next time. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's immediate children selector. Introduced in CSS 2.1.

You can find out more in this question:
[What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)