# How to change the attribute value of an element with by another element Selector in HTML + CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 element Buttons and I want to change the color of one when I click another, and vice versa. I tried It, but don't work. Can anyone help Me?
HTML:

```
<button id="t1">Test 1</button>
<button id="t2">Test 2</button>
```

CSS:

```
#t1:active + #t2
{
    color: red;
}
#t2:active + #t1
{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Wex: The question doesn't mention JavaScript at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of to achieve this using CSS only, although they aren't completely "sincere".

The first method relies on creating a "fake" clone of the first button, and showing it when the second button is `:active`, demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Jxvck/).

The second method relies on the fact that when one of your `button`s is `:active`, then parent elements behind it are `:active` as well. Here's a demo of this solution: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/hk7jv).

Comment: It is possible to do it without the div.Container??

Comment: @user1628488 The first method doesn't use a container. The second method does require a container.

Answer (score 2):

There is no vice versa, as sibling combinators only work in one direction (from an earlier sibling to a later sibling). In other words, using CSS, you can only change `#t2` when `#t1` is clicked, but not `#t1` when `#t2` is clicked. Also, [`>` is the child combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905), not a sibling combinator.

If you need the same behavior to work both ways, you have to use a JavaScript mousedown event instead of the `:active` selector.

Comment: Thank You, BoltClock. I will use Javascript

Comment: @user1628488 I hate to disagree with you, BoltClock, but this achievable without JavaScript: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/hk7jv).

Comment: @Abody97: Well, yeah, of course it works if you apply `:active` to the parent and then activate within the parent (that isn't `#t1`). I'm saying it's not possible to have the style take effect only when the second button is activated.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, sorry :) Although you can get something pretty close if you wrap them in a `div` and only act when that `div` is active: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/hk7jv). But yeah, you're right, it's conceptually impossible to do without any 'hacks'.

Comment: @user1628488 Another hack-y solution, which uses a duplicate of the first button: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/97QXF/).

Comment: @Abody97: Now *that* is clever ;)

Comment: @BoltClock I've merged those two methods into an answer and posted it. Hope you don't mind :)