# ul li a affecting ul li ul li a

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

If the title is hard to understand, let me explain...

I have a css / jquery toggle menu. When you press the "+" sign it gets bigger, when you press the "-" sign it gets smaller. I made the padding, margin and height of several elements change on toggle / click. The menu is full of links up top, then when you hover over the links it reveals more sub-links. The main links up top use the css code:

```
/*Top level menu link items style*/
.jquerycssmenu ul li a{
    display: block;
    background: none; /*background of tabs (default state)*/
    padding: 5px 18px 32px 18px;
    margin-right: 3px; /*spacing between tabs*/
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The sub menus use this css code:

```
/* Sub level menu links style */
.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a{
    font: normal 13px Verdana;
    width: 320px; /*width of sub menus*/
    height:60px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
    padding:20px 0px 0 20px;
}
```

I have set up the JQuery so sub menus padding shrinks via toggle... I did it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.gh-gallink').toggle(
    function() {
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a').animate({
      height: "40px",
      padding: "10px 0px 0 20px"
    }, 100);
    $(this).text('+');
  },

  function() {
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a').animate({
      height: "60px",
      padding: "20px 0px 0 20px"
    }, 100);
    $(this).text('-');

  });
});
```

This works perfectly fine!  I then tried to enter in the JQuery for the main menus (.jquerycssmenu ul li a)  I did it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.gh-gallink').toggle(
    function() {
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a').animate({
      height: "40px",
      padding: "10px 0px 0 20px"
    }, 100);
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li a').animate({
      paddingBottom: "8px"
    }, 100);
    $(this).text('+');
  },

  function() {
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li ul li a').animate({
      height: "60px",
      padding: "20px 0px 0 20px"
    }, 100);
    $('.jquerycssmenu ul li a').animate({
      paddingBottom: "32px"
    }, 100);
    $(this).text('-');

  });
});
```

For some reason, the `ul li a` (main menu) effects the `ul li ul li a` (sub menu).  As soon as you toggle the menu, the `padding-bottom` for the sub menus is the same for the main menu.. `32px` when bigger and `8px` when smaller.. when the `padding-bottom` should be `0px` when bigger and `0px` when smaller like listed above.

Why is `ul li a` (the main menu links) effecting `ul li ul li a` (the sub menu links)? And how can I fix this CSS / JQuery issue so that the main menu links doesn't effect the sub menu links.

**Just a quick note:** 
*I can sucesfully edit the `ul li a` code without it affecting the `ul li ul li a` code.. in CSS. It's just when I apply the codes to JQuery is when things mess up.*

Comment: If you could include the HTML and a jsfiddle of the code it would be easier for us to help.

Comment: using `.toggle()` in this fashion is deprecated.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at SMACSS (http://smacss.com/), which discusses just this type of thing. At some point layering on the specificity in your css rules becomes a fool's game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud use this:

```
`.jquerycssmenu > ul > li > a`
```

Instead of this:

```
`.jquerycssmenu ul li a`
```

Here is an explanation of the `>` css selector: 
[What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

Answer (score 2):

The selector `ul li a` matches any `<a>` tag at any depth in a `<li>` tag in a `<ul>` tag - even if, e.g., the `<li>` is actually inside an `<ol>` tag that is inside the outer `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li><a>Foo</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

A selector `ul li` has two matches for this markup as there are two `<li>` tags inside that `<ul>`. However, to select only direct childrens, you can use `>`, i.e. `ul > li` will select only the first `<li>` element but not the second one as that one is not a direct child of the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2):

`p span` means looks for a `span` element that lies within a `p` element, regardless of whether it is a direct descendant or not.

That is why, `ul li a` is also affecting a `a` that is nested like this: `ul > li > ul > li > a`.

You should use the child selector `ul > li > a`.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `ul li a` means "an `a` that is a descendant of an `li` that is a descendant of a `ul`. Anytime an `a` has an `li` and `ul` as ancestors, it will apply. To select only direct children, use the `>` operator. So `.jquerycssmenu > ul > li > a` and `.jquerycssmenu > ul > li > ul > li > a`, or something like that.