# How to create a nested vertical menu with horizontally sub-menus using css

Tags: css, menu

I want to change a list to be vertical but after changing a lot of css code the inside list that should go horizontal is going vertical and i cant find why.

```
nav ul ul { display: none;}

nav ul li:hover > ul {  display: block; }

nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display:list-item;
    }
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }
    nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
    display:list-item;
    float: right; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}   

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

And this is the html markup:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="Documents.php">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Documents.php?cat=Political">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="Documents.php?cat=History">Magazines</a></li>
                <li><a href="Documents.php?cat=Culture">MusicCd's</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="html/about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the parent menu items to be positioned vertically (go down each other) and the nested sub-menus to be positioned horizontally (to go to left of each other).

suppose it's our html markup:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Parent 1
            <ul>
                <li>Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
                <li>Child 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Parent 2
            <ul>
                <li>Child 4</li>
                <li>Child 5</li>
                <li>Child 6</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

to position the parent menu items we just tell them to `clear` their `left`. so no element can be floated to their right:

```
nav > ul > li {
    clear: left;
}
```

(also note that to specify only the parent menu item we have used `>` the [Child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators). so this style will not effect inner `li`s. only parent `li`s get that css property.)

Then we hide the sub-menu items and let them only appear only on mouse over:

```
nav > ul > li ul {
    display: none;   
}

nav > ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

the last thing is to tell the sub-menu items to be floated to left and to be displayed as inline elements. so this way we get the desired horizontally oriented sub-menu items.

```
nav > ul > li ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

and here we come to tricky part of positioning sub-menu relative to parent. to do so we use `absolute` positioning for children and set the `position:relative` for their parent so the children get positioned relative to this parent not the global parent that is `body` element

```
nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
```

here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VCX7T/6/ and this is complete css code:

```
nav > ul > li {
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li ul {
     display: none;   
}

nav > ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

nav > ul > li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
}


nav > ul > li ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

Comment: the > at the css code means? for exmaple nav>ul>li ul li means inside nav inside ul the li ul li?

Comment: here is a detailed answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

Comment: :) great happy to hear that. also please consider deleting any chatty and unneeded comments above. if you think it don't need to be here for feature visitors of the question.