# What does '>' mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

What does the > sign mean in (#todoList > div) in the following javascript?

```
$('#btnClear').click(function () {
    $('#todoList > div').each(function () {
        var entity = $(this).data('entity');
        $todo.context.TodoEntries.remove(entity);
    });
    $todo.context.saveChanges(updateView);
});
```

In the Html File the #todoList is the id of a div.

```
<div id="todoList"></div>
```

And in this statement

```
 $('#wrapper>div:not(#providerSelection)')
```

What is ":not"?

Comment: Inspired by css selectors means first level children

Comment: This is actually like a basic CSS selector. You feed that into Jquery to select elements. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules

Comment: Please read: [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Answer (score 8):

It's a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). This is not a javascript feature but css. jQuery [implement it](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) on its selector engine but it has nothing to do with javascript.

> A child selector matches when an element is the child of some element. A child selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by ">".
>
> The following rule sets the style of all P elements that are children of BODY:
>
> **body > P { line-height: 1.3 }**
>
> The following example combines descendant selectors and child selectors:
>
> **div ol>li p**
>
> It matches a P element that is a descendant of an LI; the LI element must be the child of an OL element; the OL element must be a descendant of a DIV. Notice that the optional white space around the ">" combinator has been left out.

Comment: It's a Selectors API feature, and the JavaScript DOM implements its `querySelector[All]` methods with most of that API. jQuery/Sizzle uses `.querySelectorAll()` as the default for its DOM selection.

Answer (score 7):

It's not JavaScript syntax but CSS selector syntax, here passed in a JQuery selector.

It's the ["direct child" selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

It means it selects all div elements that are child nodes one level down from the element with id `todoList`.

This would apply to elements with id A and B here :

```
<div id="todoList">
  <div id=A>
     <div id=C>
  </div>
  <span id=D></span>
  <div id=B></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#todoList > div")` means select div elements that are direct descendants (children) of the element with id="todoList".

Answer (score 0):

its a css selector, no meaning in javascript itself except "greater than",
in css it means the previous selectors direct child.

Answer (score 0):

Its a child selector of parent

*Selects all direct child elements specified by “child” of elements specified by “parent”.*

Means child `div` inside `#todoList`

SEE API `-->` http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

*The child combinator (E > F) can be thought of as a more specific form of the descendant combinator (E F) in that it selects only first-level descendants.*