# How can the width/height of an image be controlled via external stylesheet instead of using attributes?

Tags: css, image, height, width

```
<div id="leftContent">
<div style="text-align: center">
<img src="S.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Now i have a stylesheet 'main.css' linked with this page...
since i haven't set the width/height of img in the code itself
I wanna set that via styling in main.css.
How can I do that..?

P.S.: I don't have access to HTML file of the page.. I only have the access to the style sheet.

Comment: #leftContent div img {height:XX;width:XX;} , see to learn and how to use CSS selector. It's the 101 tool to build your style sheets :)  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your external stylesheet.

```
#leftContent div img{your attributes}
```

Answer (score 4):

use width and height in css

```
#leftContent img {
   width: ... ;
   height: ... ;
}
```

you may also create a specific css rule for each different image (no matter about parent container) if you are using them several times across the site with different templates, e.g.

```
img[src="S.jpg"] {
   width: ... ;
   height: ... ;
}
```

Comment: I can't imagine, with the given code, that you have other images there (that's why I used a not too specific selector):  anyway see the second part of my answer: with the attribute selector you can assign a specific size to your `S.jpg` even if you move it elsewhere.

Comment: Second one will not be useful in case of a CMS where the src of the img gets changed per reload randomly e.g. Claroline.

Comment: of course, but for a generic question with no costraints you will get a generic answer unable to deal with all edge cases :)

Answer (score 1):

try this: 
if you want to select a specific img

```
#leftContent div img:nth-child(2 or 3 or 4 or) {  //here number of the img.. 2 for the 2.
   width: yourValue;
   height: yourValue;
}
```

and else

```
#leftContent div img { 
   width: yourValue;
   height: yourValue;
}
```

Comment: It gets applied to all the images in #leftContent... anyways thnks

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/UbN7M/2/

```
CSS

#leftContent > div > img{
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;


}
```

Comment: Its working even without these '>' ...whats the purpose of '>' ??

Comment: Look at it :) -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules