# CSS: Select first-child in ACTUAL SCOPE

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to know how to select first-child in actual scope, let me give you an example so you could understand my question correctly:

HTML:

```
<div class="comment commentCompany">
  <div class="commentTop"></div>
  <div class="commentMiddle">
    Text of comment level two comment.
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="commentTop"></div>
      <div class="commentMiddle">
        Text of comment level three.
        </div>
      <div class="commentBottom"></div> 
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="commentBottom"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS that first came to my mind to affect classes commentTop, commentMiddle, commentBottom inside the commentCompany class but only in a direct scope was this:

```
.commentCompany .commentTop:first-child{/*affect company's .commentTop*/}
.commentCompany .commentMiddle:first-child{/*affect company's .commentMiddle*/}
.commentCompany .commentBottom:first-child{/*affect company's .commentBottom*/}
```

But there are two problems: :first-child is more like first class's element's type(not really a first-child of class) (would have to use nth-child), and the **main problem** : it affects also the nested comment - which is not company's comment - **so how to get only the direct scope of commentCompany?**

***I would like to know CSS2 && CSS3 solution if there is any difference. Thanks! :)***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the child combinator `>`, not the `:first-child` or `:nth-child()` pseudo-classes:

```
.commentCompany > .commentTop
.commentCompany > .commentMiddle
.commentCompany > .commentBottom
```

This only selects `.commentTop`, `.commentMiddle` and `.commentBottom` that are directly nested within `.commentCompany` (within your so-called "actual scope"). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules/3225905#3225905) for an illustration.

Using the space, the descendant combinator, means you're trying to get every first child of its parent that is nested within `.commentCompany`. Combine that with your class selectors and you get all kinds of unexpected results.

The child combinator is part of CSS2; there is no CSS3-only solution.

Comment: not to mention the :first-child and :nth-child() act very differently between CSS2 and CSS3

Comment: @Charles380: `:first-child` is identical to `:nth-child(1)`.

Comment: @BoltClock sorry with CSS2 there wasn't an :nth-child() that's what I was getting at

Comment: @BoltClock I've edited the answer and added "Here is a JSFiddle show-up: http://jsfiddle.net/36N6t/ 
(notice the color behaviour - if you dont set it anywhere before the red will be used (nested will inherit))" - just for the case you wont accept the edit :)