# Difference between using > and nothing CSS

Tags: css, nested

Well, this is a really simple question.

I really can't understand what's the real difference between using > and nothing in CSS.

HTML

```html
<p>
    Some text <h3>here</h3>
</p>
```

CSS

```css
p > h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

p h3 {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Can someone explain me this?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: Refer: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: You are aware that paragraphs are not allowed to contain headlines, aren’t you …?

Comment: @TamilSelvan Thank you, I found this article really interesting.

Comment: @CBroe Yes. The thing is that I'm sleepy and tired and I just wanted to write fast and get a rapid answer and I never noticed that error. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p > h3 {}` refers only to direct `h3` childs of the paragraph

`p h3{}` refers to every `h3` in the paragraph

The first one would not work at this example:

```
<p>
    Some text <span><h3>here</h3></span>
</p>
```