# What is ">" doing in Css

Tags: html, css

I have a question about css,

In some bootstrap files I see ">" :

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    float: none;
}

I am not sure what exactly is ">" in that phrase

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-means-in-css-rules Possible duplicate

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=css+selectors&oq=css+selectors&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1905j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean
You can find the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

`child combinator selector`

This means it will only select list items that are direct children of an `.nav-tabs.nav-justified`. In otherwords, it only looks one level down the markup structure, no deeper. So if there was another `div` list nested deeper, the list item children of it will not be targeted by this selector.

Answer (score -1):

Selects all "li" elements where the parent is element that has class "nav-tabs" and "nav-justified"