# CSS selector difference: element element vs element>element

Tags: css

What is the difference between the following two CSS selectors?

From the explanation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), they sound the same?

```
div p{}
```

Selects all p elements inside div elements

```
div > p{}
```

Selects all `p` elements where the parent is a `div` element.

Comment: [The > combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) separates two selectors and **matches only those elements** matched by the second selector that are **direct children** of elements matched by the first.

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wj8wm9fe/
That said, this isn't a good question. You could easily have figured out the difference with a bit more research.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: why this severe down vote ?? Incredible ! He did not kill any one, he just asks explanation for something he does not understand !

Comment: The duplicate suggestion answers this question. I should have searched better. No idea what I should do in this situation - delete this question? Sorry!

Comment: you can unaccept the answer and do not vote on any of the answers. Then you can delete your question

Comment: I'd say the "duplicate" question does not answer this question fully. This question asks for the difference between `element element` and `element>element`. The other does not explain the difference, but only how the `element>element` selector operates.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The difference is depth. What the w3schools site doesn't explain very well is that `E>F` only matches immediate children of `E`, while `E F` matches descendants of any depth.

Using your example CSS, consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<div>
    <p id="paragraph1">I'm paragraph 1</p>
    <ul>
        <li><p id="paragraph2">I'm paragraph 2</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The first ruleset, `div p`, will match both `p` blocks. The second one, `div > p`, will only match `paragraph1`.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what they don't like about this answer?

Comment: I found it perfectly helpful. I didn't understand how a direct descendant was different and this explained it thanks.

Comment: This is super cool and simple explanation.... thank @Jason Baker

Answer (score 4):

```
div p{}
```

This one applies to all `p` inside `div`

```
div>p{}
```

This one says `p` needs to be a direct descendent of div

Answer (score 3):

```css
/*This one applies to all childrens (`span`) inside parent*/
div span {
    color: red;
}

/*This one says child (`span`) needs to be a direct descendent of parent*/
div > span {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!--(`div`) does not represent an obstacle in both selectors-->
  <div>
    <span>I live in Duckburg.</span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>I live in Duckburg.</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>I live in Duckburg.</span><br>
  <span>I live in Duckburg.</span>
</div>
```