# Align the right border of submenu to the right border of its parent element

Tags: css

I am trying to understand a tutorial on making a CSS dropdown menu.

[image]
<sub>(source: [line25.com](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/4.jpg))</sub>

In the image above, the **left border** of the submenu is aligned to the **left border** of the parent. I want the **right border** of the submenu to align to the **right border** of the parent, whilst **retaining the submenu's width**. i.e. the submenu should be translated to the left a little.

I tried to add `position: relative;` to the direct parent of the submenu, but the text "Web Design" breaks into 2 lines; that's ugly.

The tutorial is from [dropdown menu](https://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu).

Here is my code:

```css
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul {
  background: #efefef;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  /*position: relative;*/
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
  background: #5f6975;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would relatively position the parent `li` element:

```
nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
}
```

and then set the position of the direct `ul` child to `right: 0`:

```
nav > ul > li > ul {
    right: 0;
}
```

In doing so, the child `ul` is absolutely positioned *relative* to the parent.

..and if you want to prevent the text from wrapping, add `white-space: nowrap`.

```
nav > ul > li > ul {
    right: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Is there diffenent to use nav > ul > li {position: relative;} instead of nav ul li {position: relative;} here?

Comment: @JACKM `>` is a [direct child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators). It ensures that only the direct child is selected. In this case, it prevents the ancestor `li` elements from being relatively positioned. You might want to look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3225891/2680216