# What does ">" mean in jQuery and how to use it?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery code, and recently saw a code like this:

```
var $pages = $('#main > div');
```

does that mean $pages will be the first div under #main or all the divs under #main?
If I have the HTML code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="sub-div" id="1">1</div>
        <div id="1a">1a</div>
    <div class="sub-div" id="2">2</div>
    <div class="sub-div" id="3">3</div>
</div>
```

so, will $pages be an array contain all 3 divs or only the first one?

Additionally, can I use

```
var $pages = $('#main > div > div');
```

to get "1a" ?

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: This is the jQuery child selector - it selects direct descendants of the specified parent. So in this case, only the elements with class `sub-div` would be selected. http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: Have you read [any](http://api.jquery.com/) [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)?

Comment: Try http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/ to learn about CSS selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$pages will be all immediate child divs of #main.
If you have

```
<div id=main>
    <div id=1>
        <div id=2></div>
    </div>
    <div id=3></div>
    <div id=4></div>
    <span id=5>
        <div id=6></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then `$('#main > div')` will fetch 1, 3, and 4.

If you did `$('#main div')` then you're finding all matching descendants, not just immediate ones, so that would match 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6.

Comment: in your case, if I have var $pages = $('#main > div'), then have var page1 = $pages[0] and var page2 = $pages[1], will "page1" fetch 1 and "page2" fetch 3?

Comment: Yes, but using `$pages[number]` (or its equivalent, `$pages.get(number)`) will fetch a dom object as opposed to a jquery object. Using `$pages.eq(number)` will fetch a jquery object. Use whichever suits your purposes best!

Answer (score 0):

It does the same thing as the CSS selector ">"
It returns the children of an element that have the characteristic mentioned in the right hand part.

ex.

```
var $pages = $('#main > div');
```

Would return an array of all the `div`s which are children of the element with id "main"

therefore

```
var $pages = $('#main > div > div');
```

would return the `div`s that are children of the `div`s of the element with id "main".

Only one of the divs in pages has a child div and that is the div with id "1a"