# Scrape all child paragraphs under heading (preferable rvest)

Tags: r, css-selectors, web-scraping, rvest

My objective is to use the `library(tm)` toolkit on a pretty big word document. The word document has sensible typography, so we have `h1` for the main sections, some `h2`and `h3` subheadings. I want to compare and text mine each section (the text below each `h1` - the subheadings is of little importance - so they can be included or excluded.)

My strategy is to export the worddocument to html and then use the `rvest`pacakge to extract the paragraphs.

```
library(rvest)
# the file has latin-1 chars
#Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale="da_DK.UTF-8")
# small example html file
file <- rvest::html("https://83ae1009d5b31624828197160f04b932625a6af5.googledrive.com/host/0B9YtZi1ZH4VlaVVCTGlwV3ZqcWM/tidy.html", encoding = 'utf-8')

nodes <- file %>%
  rvest::html_nodes("h1>p") %>%
  rvest::html_text()
```

I can extract all the `<p>`with `html_nodes("p")`, but thats just one big soup. I need to analize each `h1` separately.

The best would probably be a list, with a vector of `p` tags for each `h1` heading. And maybe a loop with somehting like `for (i in 1:length(html_nodes(fil, "h1"))) (html_children(html_nodes(fil, "h1")[i]))` (which is not working).

Bonus if there is a way to tidy words html from within `rvest`

Comment: You can use the [`htmltidy`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/htmltidy) package (which wraps `libtidy`) to tidy ugly Word-generated HTML in R directly now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that [`>` is the child combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean/3225905#3225905); the selector that you currently have looks for `p` elements that are children *of an `h1`*, which doesn't make sense in HTML and so returns nothing.

If you inspect the generated markup, at least in the example document that you've provided, you'll notice that every `h1` element (as well as the heading for the table of contents, which is marked up as a `p` instead) has an associated parent `div`:

```html
<body lang="EN-US">
  <div class="WordSection1">
    <p class="MsoTocHeading"><span lang="DA" class='c1'>Indholdsfortegnelse</span></p>
    ...
  </div><span lang="DA" class='c5'><br clear="all" class='c4'></span>

  <div class="WordSection2">
    <h1><a name="_Toc285441761"><span lang="DA">Interview med Jakob skoleleder på
    a_skolen</span></a></h1>
    ...
  </div><span lang="DA" class='c5'><br clear="all" class='c4'></span>

  <div class="WordSection3">
    <h1><a name="_Toc285441762"><span lang="DA">Interviewet med Andreas skoleleder på
    b_skolen</span></a></h1>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

All of the `p` elements in each section denoted by an `h1` are found in its respective parent `div`. With this in mind, you could simply select `p` elements that are siblings of each `h1`. However, since rvest doesn't currently have a way to select siblings from a context node (`html_nodes()` only supports looking at a node's subtree, i.e. its descendants), you will need to do this another way.

Assuming HTML Tidy creates a structure where every `h1` is in a `div` that is directly within `body`, you can grab every `div` except the table of contents using the following selector:

```
sections <- html_nodes(file, "body > div ~ div")
```

In your example document, this should result in `div.WordSection2` and `div.WordSection3`. The table of contents is represented by `div.WordSection1`, and that is excluded from the selection.

Then extract the paragraphs from each `div`:

```
for (section in sections) {
  paras <- html_nodes(section, "p")
  # Do stuff with paragraphs in each section...

  print(length(paras))
}
# [1] 9
# [1] 8
```

As you can see, `length(paras)` corresponds to the number of `p` elements in each `div`. Note that some of them contain nothing but an `&nbsp;` which may be troublesome depending on your needs. I'll leave dealing with those outliers as an exercise to the reader.

Unfortunately, no bonus points for me as rvest does not provide its own HTML Tidy functionality. You will need to process your Word documents separately.