# CSS Selector differences

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

this question has probably asked and answered a million times but I just want to know the difference of using `.div1 > .div1-1` compare to `.div1 .div1-1`.

I know that ">" is child selector so `.div1 (parent) > .div1-1 (child)`.

```
<div class="div1">
<div class="div1-1">Test</div>
</div>

.div1 > .div1-1{ color:red;}
```

Which approach is the best practice to use?

Comment: The one that meets your needs.

Comment: `>` means only children (and not grandchildren). Which is best? It depends on your structure.

Comment: have you already tried to google it?

Comment: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/ is very instructive

Comment: @DanielPinzon In term of specificity, they both have the same value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

Comment: @HashemQolami seems you are right will delete my comment :)

Comment: What's with the negative points? Well yeah I know it will depend on my structure but the questions was about which is better approach? @ggzone Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Why are there so many comments and down-votes before anyone bothers to answer the question? And no explanation for the down-votes?

Comment: @nCore the negative votes are a response of a "bad" question. You answered it yourself by pointing to that phrase: "this question has probably asked and answered a million times". There is enough docu,answers outside and even here in stackoverflow.

Comment: @ggzone I still don't see why there'd be so many negative points whilst the link you've provided is no different from what I have. Also no vote-down explanation as Ted said which is annoying when the rules said "provide your reason".

Comment: @nCore it is a big community with some superbrains here. dont think they are all correct and following the rules. I am not a downvoter but i can understand them. But yes you are right every commentless downvote should have something like "there is enough docu" as sidenote

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<style>
    .div1 .div1-1 {color: red;} /* all children */
    .div1 > .div1-1 {background: blue;} /* direct children */
</style>

<div class="div1">
    <div class="div1-1">Test</div>
</div>

// both .div1 > .div1-1 and .div1 .div1-1 do the same
// both rules are applied
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yb1Lfsd8/

vs.

```
<style>
    .div1 .div1-1 {color: red;} 
    .div1 > .div1-1 {background: blue;}
</style>

<div class="div1">
    <div>
        <div class="div1-1">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>

// Just .div1 .div1-1 change styles to '.div1-1'
// The first rule is applied only
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yb1Lfsd8/1/

Comment: What are you asking the OP to "try" here?