# What does an a (> *) do in a CSS selector?

Tags: css

for example for this code: (I know about star but not '> *')

```
.row > * {
        float: right;
    }
```

or this one:

```
.row.uniform > * > :first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: Basically the first block will select ALL elements which are the direct child of the row class. The child elements of the first level children will not be styled.

Answer (score 0):

The `>` combinator separates two selectors and matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first.

Answer (score 0):

It selects all the elements where the parent is the one infront of `>` selector.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` selects all elements, the `.row >` selects all elements where the parent is a `.row` element.

See the [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23attribute-selectors).

Answer (score 0):

The `*` selector is a wild card selector so will select all elements.

The `>` selector says "Only the next element of what you specify"

So `> *` will all select the next element no matter what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The > selector in CSS is used to select child elements.

.row > * will style ALL elements within the parent class row.

Answer (score 0):

">" means direct children elements. So that it will select all direct children of "row" elements.