# Limit toggle to work with only parent element

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html list with the following structure:

```
<ul id="dunderList">
  <li>Characters</li>
<div>
   <li>scott</li>
   <li>halpert</li>
   <li>beasley</li>
   <li>schrute</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

I want to toggle the div on click of the first ul with the id 'dunderList' but limit it to only click of that element. Right now with my jquery code even if I click the child list the div toggles.

js:

```
$(document).on('tap', '#dunderList', function() {

    $(this).find('div').toggle();
});
```

So, if I click on 'scott' the list shouldn't toggle but right now it does.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95hk2hjz/6/)

Comment: Check [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/95hk2hjz/7/)

Comment: div is not a valid child of ul, also are you saying you have multiple elements with the id dunderList? id must be unique, if you need to have multiple elements, you need to use class instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html is not valid as `ul` can have only `li` as its child.

You can have the click handler to target only the first `li` element, then toggle all its sibling elements like

```js
//event name is changed to click to simulate the functioning here... change it to tap in your case
$(document).on('click', '#dunderList > li:first-child', function() {
  $(this).siblings().toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dunderList">
  <li>Characters</li>
  <li>scott</li>
  <li>halpert</li>
  <li>beasley</li>
  <li>schrute</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Arun!! was that event `tap` or `click`? cs when I ran your snippet it wasn't running! So just edited and made it to click!

Comment: Oh Ok. Looks fine then.. :) You can revert it back buddy.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response...I am new to jquery what does '>' do in '#dunderList > li:first-child'

Comment: @bos570 that is the child selector... not really required... you can just say `#dunderList li:first-child` with the above given markup

Comment: `>` is the [child combinator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean#3225905), or direct descendant combinator. It makes sure you are only matching the `li`s that are directly descendant of `#dunderList`, not from any nested `ul` you might have in the future.

Answer (score 0):

change your click handler to fire on the first list element, then find the div and toggle it:

```
$(document).on('tap', '#dunderList > li:first-child', function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('div').toggle();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95hk2hjz/8/