# Jsoup Selector Syntax Not Working as Expected

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

For the following HTML:

```
<table> 
 <tbody>
  <tr valign="TOP">
   <td align="LEFT"><b>Licensee Name:</b></td>
   <td align="LEFT">Some-last-name Some-first-name</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr valign="TOP">
   <td align="LEFT"><b>License Type:</b></td>
   <td align="LEFT">Optometrist (OPT)</td>
  </tr> 
.
.
.
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The following code produces an empty collection of Elements:

```
Elements rows = docOptometristDetail.select("body > table ~ tr");
```

But this code works:

```
tables = docOptometristDetail.select("body > table");
Elements rows = tables.select("tr");
```

I was expecting the tilde operator:

```
table ~ tr
```

to find the `<table>` element, skip the `<tbody>` element and build a collection of the `<tr>` elements.

Have I uncovered a weakness in Jsoup's selector syntax parser or am I attempting to violate some operator precedence rules?

I tried `(body > table) ~ tr` but that throws a `SelectorParseException`.

Is there a way to do this selection (i.e. getting an `Elements` collection of `<tr>` elements) with a single selector expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, the tilde character, `~`, is a [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

The selector `table ~ tr` will attempt to select the `tr` sibling elements *following* the the `table` element. Since `table` elements and `tr` elements can't be siblings, nothing will be selected.

In theory, the selector `table ~ tr` would select the `tr` elements below:

```
<table></table>
<tr></tr> <!-- These 'tr' elements are following siblings of the 'table' -->
<tr></tr> <!-- This is invalid HTML, though. -->
```

It sounds like you just need to select the descendants, therefore `body > table tr` will work.

Comment: This does work!  Thanks.  If the table is inside the body, you get to it via "body > table".  So if the rows are inside the table, why don't you use "table > tr" (which I had previously tried, with no success)?

Comment: @mbmast It's because `>` will select *direct* children elements, whereas a space will select all descendants. The `tr` elements are not direct children of the `table` element, but they are descendants. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean