# What is the purpose of > in a CSS file

Tags: html, css

I am currently editing a CSS file from a Joomla template, and I came across this line: `.promo > .gantry-width-block:hover{margin-top:-35px;padding-top:35px;}`

What is the purpose of the `>` marker in between promo and gantry..?

Ps. I don't know if marker is the correct word, probably not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: This is duplicate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` is a direct child selector, `.promo > .gantry` addresses all elements with a class `gantry` that are a direct child of any element with the class `promo`.

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)

```
    div > p {
       background-color: yellow;
    }
```

> Select and style every p element where the parent is a div element

Answer (score 0):

This means direct descendant. This is worth a read http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

> A child combinator describes a childhood relationship between two elements. A child combinator is made of the "greater-than sign" (U+003E, >) character and separates two sequences of simple selectors.
>
> Examples:
>
> The following selector represents a p element that is child of body:
>
> body > p The following example combines descendant combinators and
>   child combinators.
>
> div ol>li p It represents a p element that is a descendant of an li
>   element; the li element must be the child of an ol element; the ol
>   element must be a descendant of a div. Notice that the optional white
>   space around the ">" combinator has been left out.

Reference https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators

Answer (score 0):

It means direct descendant.

For example, the `footer` here is a direct descendant, while `p` is not.

```
<div>
    <footer>
        <p>
        </p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It means immediate children.

It refers to direct children of certain elements .

Example 1:

```
Parent_1

 child_1

 child_1

Parent_2

 child_2
```

Example 2:

```
<div>
    <p class="some_class">Some text here</p>     <!-- Selected [1] -->
    <blockquote>
        <p class="some_class">More text here</p> <!-- Not selected [2] -->
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

hat means the selector `div > p.some_class` only selects paragraphs of `.some_class` that sit directly inside a div, not paragraphs that are nested further within.

[Check here more..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

[check here more.. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)