# Increase textbox height in Spring Form

Tags: html, css, spring-form

I have a spring-mvc form with a text box: I want to increase the height of the text box. I have tried adding the "height" and "line-height" properties in css but my textbox height doesn't change at all.
Form:

```
<div class="plLabelSearch">Code:</div> 
<div class="plinput"><form:input path="codeKey" type="text" size="29"/></div>
```

css properties:

```
.plLabelSearch{display:inline-block;width:190px;text-align:right;margin-bottom:10px;}
.plinput{display:inline-block;width:150px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not targeting the `<input>` correctly, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/15/

`.plinput > input{height: 50px;}`

Comment: Thanks it helped. If anyone is wondering about the '>' symbol,Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean