# Purpose of greater than in $('.aclassname > input ')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have been looking at someone jquery code in jsf and I am not sure if I 100% clear I understand it all. The I am not clear on is the following syntax

```
    $('aclassname > input').each(function {}
```

What I am trying to understand is how the greater than symbol is working here.  The 'aclassname' is a class attribute used on a div tag and this tag is wrapped round a input button. I know that the action is change an event on the button, but how does the greater than symbol work on this?

Comment: This should help. Same rules as in CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: The `>` is a child selector. If `aclassname` is a class, place a `.` before the class name. `$('.aclassname > input')` means: "find every element with the class name of, 'aclassname' , then select every input element that is *directly* under it. Directly under an element essentially children, if the children had children of it's own (grandchildren?), then those grandchildren would not be included in the selection.

Comment: "." is require before class name , without "." mean consider as tag.