# CSS triple descendant selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've a doubt on descendant selectors...

```
.classA .classB .classC{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

This applies the background to all the classC elements, child (direct or indirect) of classB elements, where classB element is a child (direct or indirect) of a classA element. This doesn't apply a background to classC elements child of classA elements, but non-child of classB elements. Is this right?

```
.classA > .classB .classC{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Thiss applies the background to all the classC elements, child (direct or indirect) off all classB elements, where classB element is a DIRECT (non indirect) child of a class A element.

Is everything right?

Comment: > checks the immediate children, so the latter rule applies to .classC elements which are indirect or direct descendants of .classB which are children (immediate) of .classA

Answer (score 2):

Everything you have said is right, except substitute "descendant" for "child". A "direct child" is a tautology; a child is an immediate descendant by definition. Conversely, in the selector `E > F > G`, G is a descendant of E, but not its child; it is its grandchild.

It's why `>` is known as simply the child combinator, or alternatively the direct descendant combinator, but not the "direct child" combinator.

See also: [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean/3225905#3225905) (particularly the footnote of my answer there)