# How to write nested CSS classes with arrow sign in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

How to write the below css code with arrows in sass?

```
.membersList ul.pagination > .active > a {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}
```

What's the difference between above and below

CSS:

```
.membersList ul.pagination .active a {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}
```

SASS:

```
 .membersList
{
 ul.pagination {
   .active 
   {
     a {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: See this SO question on `>` [**What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean) which should highlight the difference when using `>` vs not using it. Documentation on [**Child Combinator**](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators)

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `.membersList ul.pagination > .active > a` and `.membersList ul.pagination .active a` is, that `.active` has to be in the first case an immediate child of `ul.pagination` and in the second case, it can be also lower (with intermediate elements in between). The same is true for the `a` element.

---

For example, with the following HTML structure you can see the difference:

1. Selector `.membersList ul.pagination > .active > a`
2. Selector `.membersList ul.pagination .active a`

**HTML structure, matches 1+2**: <kbd>.membersList</kbd> → <kbd>ul.pagination</kbd> → <kbd>.active</kbd> → <kbd>a</kbd>

**HTML structure, matches only 2**: <kbd>.membersList</kbd> → <kbd>ul.pagination</kbd> → <kbd>li</kbd> → <kbd>.active</kbd> → <kbd>a</kbd>

**HTML structure, matches only 2**: <kbd>.membersList</kbd> → <kbd>ul.pagination</kbd> → <kbd>li</kbd> → <kbd>.active</kbd> → <kbd>span</kbd> → <kbd>a</kbd>

---

You can use the arrow sign in SASS as well:

```
.membersList {
   ul.pagination {
      > .active {
         > a {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
         }
      }
   }
}
```