# nth-of-type selector not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I only want to select the first `h2` and first `p` from `#section_5`, thus I used this CSS:

```css
#section_5 div:nth-of-type(1) h2{
    color:green;
}
#section_5 div:nth-of-type(1) p{
    color:blue;
}
```

But it selects all other children divs of `#section_5` which doesn't seem to satisfy the selector: `nth-of-type(1)`

```css
/*style the more features title*/
#section_5 div:nth-of-type(1) h2{
    color:green;
}

/*style the more features paragraph*/
#section_5 div:nth-of-type(1) p{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="section_5">                    
    <div class="row just_space1 title">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h2>The Limitation Of Design Is Never Ending With Our Features</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero quod consequuntur 
 quibusdam, enim expedita sed quia nesciunt incidunt accusamus necessitatibus modi 
 adipisci officia libero accusantium esse hic, obcaecati, ullam, laboriosam!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>&#xe011;</span>
                <p>Danything</p>
                <h2>anything t</h2>
                <p>anything</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>&#xe011;</span>
                <p>Danything</p>
                <h2>anything t</h2>
                <p>anything</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Features column 1 -->
 
        <!--Image to style the section-->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
            <p>
                ssss
            </p>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <div>
                <span>&#xe011;</span>
                <p>Danything</p>
                <h2>anything t</h2>
                <p>anything</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>&#xe011;</span>
                <p>Danything</p>
                <h2>anything t</h2>
                <p>anything</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
<!--/Section 5-->
```

Could you shed the light on this, or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: #section_5 p:nth-child(1){} try that

Comment: @IamCavic That didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the [`>` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean) to avoid selecting nested elements. Your selector will select all the `div` that are `nth-of-type(1)` at any level not only the `div` that are child of `#section5`.

```css
/*style the more features title*/
#section_5 > div:nth-of-type(1) h2 {
  color: green;
}


/*style the more features paragraph*/
#section_5 > div:nth-of-type(1) p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="section_5">
  <div class="row just_space1 title">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <h2>The Limitation Of Design Is Never Ending With Our Features</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero quod consequuntur quibusdam, enim expedita sed quia nesciunt incidunt accusamus necessitatibus modi adipisci officia libero accusantium esse hic, obcaecati, ullam, laboriosam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div> <!-- this div is also  nth-of-type(1) -->
      <div> <!-- this div is also  nth-of-type(1) -->
        <span>&#xe011;</span>
        <p>Danything</p>
        <h2>anything t</h2>
        <p>anything</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>&#xe011;</span>
        <p>Danything</p>
        <h2>anything t</h2>
        <p>anything</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <p>
        ssss
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div> <!-- this div is also nth-of-type(1) -->
        <span>&#xe011;</span>
        <p>Danything</p>
        <h2>anything t</h2>
        <p>anything</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>&#xe011;</span>
        <p>Danything</p>
        <h2>anything t</h2>
        <p>anything</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/Section 5-->
```