# Is CDATA necessary when styling an inline SVG?

Tags: css, xml, html, dom, svg

I've read mixed things about this, so I'm hoping to get it sorted definitively.

If I have SVG markup that is inline within an HTML document, and I am styling it with CSS, do I need to wrap that CSS in commented out CDATA?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <style type="text/css">
            /* <![CDATA[ */
            .some_styles {}
            /* ]]> */
        </style>
        <!-- SVG content here -->
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I imagine there could be issues like the [CSS child combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225905/2454914) being misinterpreted as an XML closing bracket, and I have read various posts from people advising using commented out CDATA around inline SVG styles <sup>[1](http://xahlee.info/js/svg_specify_style.html)</sup> <sup>[2](https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/details/RgMZJN)</sup>. However, to my surprise I found that even with CDATA removed and the child combinator being used, my HTML validated. In addition to this, I was unable to detect any problems with the rendering of the SVG in any modern browser.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/) what has been discussed on SE about including CDATA within a `<script>` tag, but that's not the same thing as `<svg>`, so it seemed this warranted its own question.

I don't mind including it, and doing so doesn't cause any trouble. I just wonder if I'm doing the right thing or something unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory CDATA blocks are required anywhere you'd want to write unescaped text. In XML, only 2 characters need escaping: `<` and `&` and both characters are meaningless in CSS.

That means you don't need CDATA blocks for CSS.

(Also, you don't need CDATA in HTML because HTML is not XML).