# CSS > combinator not getting result I expected

Tags: css

Im having a bit of trouble understanding how > works in CSS, I thought what ever element we are targeting, the children of that element would pass on the property.  I was wondering if there is an exception to that rule?

```html
<ul id = "outside"> 

          <li>A</li>
          <li>B</li>
          <li>C</li> 
            <ul>
              <li>D</li>
              <li>E</li>
              <li>F</li>
            </ul>
          <li>G</li>

</ul>
```

```css
#outside > li{
  color: green;
}
```

A B C are green but D E F are not

```html
<div id="three">
          three
          <div id="two">
            two
           <header id="one">
             one
             <footer id="zero">
              zero
             </footer>
           </header>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```css
#three > #two {
  color: green;
}
```

two, one, zero are green but not three

Comment: Your first code is invalid to start with, only li are allowed as child of ul

Comment: `>` is the child selector. That means, it literally selects only the children.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` operator only selects the *direct* (first gen) children of the element. In the case of `color`, the child elements of that targeted element inherit that style rule:

> A B C are green but D E F are not

Because the `li` tags `D`,`E`, and `F` are not descendants of the `li` tags targeted in the rule:

```css
#outside>li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="outside">

  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <ul>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
  </ul>
  <li>G</li>

</ul>
```

> two, one, zero are green but not three

`#three` is neither targeted nor inherited. Two is directly targeted by this rule, and `#one` and `#zero` are inheriting `#two`'s rule:

```css
#three>#two {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="three">
  three
  <div id="two">
    two
    <header id="one">
      one
      <footer id="zero">
        zero
      </footer>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You helped clear up some ambiguity I had, I wasent aware that we were able to inherit to the children, I thought we would only be able to apply our changes to the selector we targeted.  I played with the code and added an unordered list inside a <li> and the new unordered list items were green.

Comment: @ghost2092000 Technically you were right before that you can only apply changes to the selector you targeted. When a child element is affected by a style rule (e.g. `color: green`) it's because it has *inherited* that rule, not because the rule has been applied to it. Seems like a trivial distinction, I know, but it's important to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`>` is the **direct** [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator); it only applies to *child* elements, *not* grandchild or further descendants.

Each of your two examples has a different reason for not having the rule applied. The top example targets `#outside > li`. This means that only `<li>` elements that are a **direct** child of `#outside` will have the rule applied to them. This *does* cascade down to other `<li>` descendants, however, it's not applying due to the fact that the upper example has incorrect markup; only `<li>` is allowed as a child of `<ul>`. If you were to correct this markup, it would cascade as expected:

```css
#outside>li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="outside">

  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>G</li>

</ul>
```

As for your second example, the selector is `#three > #two`. This only applies to `#two`, due to the fact that the `#three >` part of the selector merely adds [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In any given CSS selector, it's only the final element in the 'chain' that has the rule applied to it; the 'navigation' components are used exclusively for specificity.

Comment: I understand the first answer for the first example, but I dont quite follow what you mean on the second example, wouldn't the word ```two``` be the only one that would be green since we only target #two and not its children?