# How to select all childs(of specific type) related to baseElement?

Tags: javascript, menu, css-selectors

Let's say my code looks like that

```js
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

//now i need to select <a> tags with 'design' and 'development', but using menu element i've already selected.

//const firstLineChilds = menu.querySelector(???);
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">DevOps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Managment</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is it even possible to to this the 'clean way'? Or i just need to use menu.parentNode.querySelector(".menu > li > a")

Answer (score 0):

You can chain querySelector and other such methods and it will search children of previous returned node: `document.querySelector(".menu").querySelectorAll("a")`  or `menu.querySelectorAll("a")`

Comment: I still get all <a> including this inside sub-menu.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the hrefs to an `Array` (in the snippet the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is used for that) enables you to filter them:

```js
const relevantHrefs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".menu li a")]
  .filter(href => ["Design", "Development"].find(h => href.textContent === h));
console.log(relevantHrefs);

// based on comment, this is maybe what OP needs
const menu = [...document.querySelectorAll(".menu > li:nth-child(-n+2) a")];
console.log(menu);
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">DevOps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Managment</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My point is, it's not about picking two two anchors with specific hrefs, but I would like to pick anchors which are inside first-line childs of ul.menu only. Just tryin to find a way to select them depending on .menu I've already selected. The logic behind this is more complicated, because menu may have diffrent class name, so I want to do this universal and complex way.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but added a css-selector that *may* be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) in conjunction with child combinators, in `menu.querySelectorAll()`:

```js
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu")
const firstLineChilds = menu.querySelectorAll(":scope > li > a");
console.log(firstLineChilds);
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">DevOps</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Managment</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you use descendant combinators, you'll still get the nested `a` elements, which is not what you want. See [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean/3225905#3225905)