# What does the '>' symbol in css mean?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Easy points here for anyone who knows. I am looking for a detailed answer on what it (`>`) means and how it should be used. Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628485/what-does-in-css-mean?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no valid symbol as `<` in CSS. If you use it, you will invalidate your css.

However, you may want to use `>` - the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

CSS4 will introduce a subject selector. At the moment it is marked with `$`.

so

```
$#parent a:hover{
   /* styles */
}
```

so these rules will not apply to the a in hoverstate, but it's parent with the `parent`-ID. [CSS4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject)

Comment: I thank you for your correction, the detailed description, and the nod to the future.

Answer (score 4):

The `<` is not valid CSS, you should not use it anywhere in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of the `>` (great than symbol) selector.

This selector is known as the child combinator selector.

This means it will only select direct children of the parent. For example:

```
ul > li
```

So for example, if you wanted to style a nested unordered list as such:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
    <li>
       <ul>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You would have to style it as such:

```
ul > li > ul
```

But this is only in the case of using `>`, child combinator selector.

Comment: `ul ul` would also catch that particular case… we could add a `ul` inside the `li` to make it more relevant, though I'm not actually sure what putting a `ul` directly inside a `ul` would do.

Comment: @Matchu: I never place a ul inside a li, if I am going to nest a ul, I make sure I put it within the ul, not the li. It have the exact same results, it just makes your HTML look cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see non-validating HTML as "cleaner" than validating HTML.

Comment: @MrLister: Regardless of the validity of the HTML in my "example", my answer to the question above is correct and I do not see why you would be concentrating on the validity of nesting an unordered list instead of answering the users question.

Comment: @AaronBrewer how you write it, it's creates invalid markup. Very dangerous since you can't rely on consistent rendering.

Comment: @Christoph: There, I have validity in my unordered list now.

Comment: now your selector does not match^^

Comment: @Christoph: Now it does.

Comment: yep. offtopic: You dont like spelling names right? ;-D